# Authentication is null Micronaut 3

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-security

I have a Micronaut 3 application, while using the JWT token the Authentication attribute on check method is null, however, I need to get all the roles from the JWT.

As per latest change from Micronaut

**SecurityRule Changes**

The SecurityRule API has changed. The last argument to the method was a map that represented the user attributes. Instead that argument was replaced with a reference to the Authentication. This has the benefit of rules now having access to the username of the logged in user as well as access to the convenience method getRoles().

```
@Singleton
public class AuthorityHandler implements SecurityRule {
    @Override
    public Publisher<SecurityRuleResult> check(HttpRequest<?> request, RouteMatch<?> routeMatch, Authentication authentication) {
        if (routeMatch instanceof MethodBasedRouteMatch methodBasedRouteMatch) {
            if (methodBasedRouteMatch.hasAnnotation(IRequirement.class)) {
                AnnotationValue<IRequirement> requiredPermissionAnnotation = methodBasedRouteMatch.getAnnotation(IRequirement.class);
                Optional<String> resourceIdName = requiredPermissionAnnotation.stringValue("resourceName");
                String[] permissions = requiredPermissionAnnotation.stringValues("permission");
                if (permissions.length > 0 && resourceIdName.isPresent() && authentication != null) {
                    List<String> identityClaims = (List<String>) authentication.getRoles();
                    if (Arrays.stream(permissions).anyMatch(element -> identityClaims.contains(element)))
                        return Mono.just(SecurityRuleResult.ALLOWED);
                    else
                        return Mono.just(SecurityRuleResult.REJECTED);
                }
            }
        }
        return Mono.just(SecurityRuleResult.UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

[image]

```
@Post
    @IRequirement(resourceName = ClaimType.TAG_PRODUCT, permission = {ClaimValue.TAG_OWNER,ClaimValue.TAG_CREATOR,ClaimValue.TAG_VIEWER })
    Mono<MutableHttpResponse<?>> post(@Body @Valid CategoryCommand model);
```

I am login to the application and passing the JWT token from request received from Identity server and it has roles as well. What I am missing or making mistake?

configuration

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: fetebirdApigateway
  server:
    port: 8080
    cors:
      enabled: true
    http-version: 2.0
  security:
    enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          jwks:
            IdentityServer:
              url: 'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'
      propagation:
        enabled: true
        header:
          enabled: true
          header-name: "Authorization"
          prefix: "Bearer "
        service-id-regex: "fetebirdProductPublisher|feteBirdService"
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /swagger-ui/**
        httpMethod: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /swagger/**
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
  router:
    static-resources:
      swagger:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**
      swagger-ui:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui
        mapping: /swagger-ui/**
tracing:
  zipkin:
    enabled: true
    http:
      url: http://localhost:9411
    sampler:
      probability: 0.1
consul:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: true
    defaultZone: ${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}:${CONSUL_PORT:8500}
jackson:
  serializationInclusion: ALWAYS
```

[image]

Decoding JWT

```
{
  "nbf": 1634908283,
  "exp": 1634908483,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "client_id": "Fete_Bird_UI",
  "sub": "673533cc-7c0b-40f3-80ac-222696df385d",
  "auth_time": 1634906895,
  "idp": "local",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "673533cc-7c0b-40f3-80ac-222696df385d",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin@local.com",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "admin@local.com",
  "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": "812aa4cb-b9f1-48ac-9e39-1f0dceb6f1c4",
  "identityserver": "owner",
  "fb_product": "owner",
  "fb_order": "owner",
  "fb_payment": "owner",
  "jti": "4AD786103632F389C21E10794E87BEC2",
  "sid": "D0423E9D4C5DDC6575448F6C65537B63",
  "iat": 1634908283,
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Claims

```
"identityserver": "owner",
  "fb_product": "owner",
  "fb_order": "owner",
  "fb_payment": "owner",
```

Comment: Are you able to enable the introspection endpoint and hit the latter? https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#introspectionendpoint

Comment: I did, 401 on http://localhost:8080/token_info

Comment: Then the token validation (using the JWKs) is failing for sure. Are you able to retrieve the contents of the key set through the configured link https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks ?

Comment: Yes I am able to fetch the content of key set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a breakpoint to [JwtValidator](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/blob/master/security-jwt/src/main/java/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/validator/JwtValidator.java)

and increase the log level for security. Add the following line in `logback.xml`:

```
<logger name="io.micronaut.security" level="TRACE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sergio del Amo I was able to find the issue with my application. It was an `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error`

Localhost certificate was not added in java cacerts.

Since I am using Intellj download java 17 the file location might be different others java sdk

Adding the certificate for application to the truststore file of the used JVM located at `/Users/macbook/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`.

Check if your certificate is already in the truststore by running the following command: `keytool -list -keystore /Users/macbook/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`

Download the certificate from browser and add it to the truststore with the following command:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
```

Example

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias falconIdentity -file /Users/macbook/Desktop/localhost.cer -keystore /Users/macbook/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts/keystore.jks -storepass changeit
```